# Associating SNP and GENE

Tags: gene, snp, hgp

Assuming I have SNPs data using hg19, how can I know which SNP belongs into which Gene?

The data looks like:

```
chr10_103577643
chr10_124712463
```

and so on.

I want to add a column of Gene, which would tell to which Gene the SNP belongs. 
The file is not a VCF file but a Txt file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your data. What do you have? A list of rsIDs? A VCF file? Some other format? How many SNPs?

Comment: Just annotate the vcf file.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Variant Effect Predictor(VEP)](http://grch37.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/index.html)

Comment: Please don't just post links as answers. It would be great if you could add a short explanation of what VEP is, how to use it etc. Otherwise, this is really a comment and not an answer and would become useless in the (admittedly unlikely) case where the VEP were to be discontinued or its URL changed. For instance, pasting `chr10_103577643` into VEP doesn't work, so you could explain what format the data would have to be in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [snpEff](http://snpeff.sourceforge.net/SnpEff_manual.html) or [snpSIFT](http://snpeff.sourceforge.net/SnpSift.html) java annotator also for hg19.

Comment: Please don't just post links as answers. It would be great if you could add a short explanation of these tools do, how to use them etc. Otherwise, this is really a comment and not an answer and would become useless if the tools were to be discontinued or their URLs changed.